# How do you convert a dictionary with objects into geoJson?

Tags: javascript, dictionary, object, geojson

We have a dictionary with cities, using a uniqe id as the key:

```
cities: {
    'adfjlx9w': {
      name: 'New York',
      latitude: 4,
      longitude: -7
    },
    'favkljsl9': {
      name: 'Copenhagen',
      latitude: 2,
      longitude: -18
    }
  }
```

We need to convert our dictionary into Geojson in order to place the cities on a map, but cannot use the typical route below, as it is not an array of objects:

```
GeoJSON.parse(cities, {
      Point: ['latitude', 'longitude']
    });
```

What is the fastest and best way to do this?

Comment: Maybe try `cities.keys().map()`?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you need to extract the `latitude` and `longitude` data for each value of the `cities` object to an array of latitude/longitude values of shape:

```
{ latitude, longitude }
```

One approach would be to use [`Object#values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) which returns an array of the values for `cities`, and, optional use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to transform each object to a new object (with only the latitude, longitude values):

```js
const cities = {
    'adfjlx9w': {
      name: 'New York',
      latitude: 4,
      longitude: -7
    },
    'favkljsl9': {
      name: 'Copenhagen',
      latitude: 2,
      longitude: -18
    }
  }  

const latlngArray = Object
// Extract value array from cities
.values(cities) 
// Map each value to lat/lng only object
.map(item => ({ latitude : item.latitude, longitude : item.longitude })) 

console.log(latlngArray);

/* Pass latlngArray to GeoJSON.parse
GeoJSON.parse(latlngArray, {
  Point: ['latitude', 'longitude']
});
*/
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work.

```js
const citiesArray = Object.values(cities);

GeoJSON.parse(citiesArray, {
      Point: ['latitude', 'longitude']
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the GeoJSON Specification, to include the `id` and `name` properties with latitude/longitude coordinates, you would need to parse the object as type `FeatureCollection` with a property `features`.

Each `features` array object should be of type `Feature`, with `properties` and `geometry` values. The `properties` value should contain the metadata, and the `geometry` value should be of type `Point` with `coordinates` property containing latitude/longitude.

```
const cities = {
  'adfjlx9w': {
    name: 'New York',
    latitude: 4,
    longitude: -7
  },
  'favkljsl9': {
    name: 'Copenhagen',
    latitude: 2,
    longitude: -18
  }
}

let citiesGeoJSON = Object.entries(cities)
  .reduce((
    _cities,
    [cityID, cityData],
  ) => {
    let city = {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "id": cityID,
        "name": cityData.name,
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": 'Point',
        "coordinates": [
          cityData.latitude,
          cityData.longitude,
        ],
      },
    }
    _cities.features.push(city)
    return _cities
  }, {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [],
  })
```

There is a [GeoJSON Linter](http://geojsonlint.com/) online.